# change Jquery dispara todos inputs de mesmo nome

Tags: jquery

Olá

Adicionei um evento *change* do jQuery em campo input com date-picker, para em toda alteração já fazer a alteração no BD. Porém, este campo input ser repete para cada usuário com o mesmo nome.

O código está funcionando normalmente, faz as alterações certinhas e salva no banco de dados para cada usuário separadamente. Porém, quando olho no log vejo que ele dispara para todos os usuários cadastrados (mesmo não afetando os demais, só que foi modificado).
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
$("input[name='last-day-training']").on('change', function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('alt');
  var last_day_training = $(this).val();
  var data = {'key':'last-day-training','last_day':last_day_training,'user':id};
  data = JSON.stringify(data);
   $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'funcoes/_planejamento.php',
    dataType : 'json',
    data : {data:data},
    success: function(data){
     console.log(data);
     if(data.sql=='ok'){
     }else{
      alert('Erro, por favor contate o administrador');
     };
    },
    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
     console.log(textStatus);
     console.log(errorThrown);
    }
   });
 });
```

```html
<input name="last-day-training" alt="<?php echo $l->id;?>" type="text" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-date-viewmode="years" class="form-control date-picker">
```

Comment: Como assim ? existem vários input's com o mesmo name?

Comment: Sim, pois tenho uma lista de usuários na mesma tela, e para cada usuário tem esse input do date-picker

Comment: Posta o codigo html tambem para facilitar o entendimento

Comment: Fiz uns testes aqui com mais usuários cadastrados e na verdade não está disparando para todos os usuários não. Só não entendi o por que de no log estar aparecendo 3 vezes. Será que é por causa do date-picker, quando atualiza?

Comment: Também não é o date-picker, testei ele separado... sei lá

Comment: Man `$("input[name='last-day-training']").on('change'...` irá disparar sim **todos** os input que tiver o name igual à **last-day-training**, uma dica coloca um name diferente p/ cada input e seja feliz